# Why do twitter-bootstrap-rails generated views use model_class.human_attribute_name(:column) instead of just a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, generator, twitter-bootstrap-rails

With twitter-bootstrap-rails installed, using the generator:

```
rails g bootstrap:themed Model
```

creates views that contain lines such as:

```
  <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:comment_date) %></th>
  <th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:comment_time) %></th>
```

where the default rails generator just inserts the human readable column name directly:

```
 <th>Comment date</th>
 <th>Comment time</th>
```

which makes for cleaner views, and seems like it would be more efficient at run-time.

Is there a benefit to the twitter-bootstrap-rails generated views?

Thanks!

(PS, The developers website is offline, and neither github nor google+ allow sending private messages, and neither an "issue" on github nor a public comment on a google+ post seemed appropriate for this question, so hoping someone here might be familiar with the use-case for model_class.human_attribute_name())

Comment: I am a complete and utter noob with RoR, so here's a comment instead of an answer: probably i18n / l10n? Does that make any sense?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter Good guess! `human_attribute_name` is indeed bothered by the internationalization stuff. So it's more appropriate in general case where you may add some locales in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at its source and things will get clear to you:

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/translation.rb, line 45
def human_attribute_name(attribute, options = {})
  defaults  = []
  parts     = attribute.to_s.split(".", 2)
  attribute = parts.pop
  namespace = parts.pop

  if namespace
    lookup_ancestors.each do |klass|
      defaults << :"#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}/#{namespace}.#{attribute}"
    end
    defaults << :"#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes.#{namespace}.#{attribute}"
  else
    lookup_ancestors.each do |klass|
      defaults << :"#{self.i18n_scope}.attributes.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}.#{attribute}"
    end
  end

  defaults << :"attributes.#{attribute}"
  defaults << options.delete(:default) if options[:default]
  defaults << attribute.humanize

  options.reverse_merge! :count => 1, :default => defaults
  I18n.translate(defaults.shift, options)
end
```

`human_attribute_name` does a great job for localizing your attribute names. Even if you're building app which uses English exclusively -- who knows, maybe your inbox already has an email from your client about his plans on expanding business and this expansion will include countries where people write right-to-left.

### How it works

Assume you have `Product` model with `title` attribute. Calling `human_attribute_name` this way:

```
Product.human_attribute_name 'title'
```

will call `I18n.t` (see the last line in the snippet above) with the following parameters:

```
I18.t 'activerecord.attributes.product.title', {
  :count=>1, 
  :default=>[:"attributes.title", "Title"] 
}
```

So, you can provide translations specific to some model and specific to some attribute's name. Unless you provide any of these translations you'll get English version of your attribute created via `humanize` method.

Comment: Isn't that what I18n.t is for? Why not t with the human readable column name as the default? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation.

Comment: So, where do I have to put my translations of the model's fields? For instance, `title: 'título'` ?